# SHAP Force Plot acts weird when a feature has missing value

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, python-3.6, shap

Given below is the code to display SHAP force plot for a row from a test set. I then update that feature to np.NAN, the force plot stops displaying many of the features.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import shap
import numpy as np

xg = pd.read_pickle("xg_raw.pkl")
train = pd.read_pickle("train.pkl")
test = pd.read_pickle("test.pkl")
y_test = pd.read_pickle('y_test.pkl')


explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xg, feature_perturbation='interventional', 
                                data=train, model_output='probability' )

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X=test)
pat = test.iloc[10]
shap.plots.force(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[10], pat, show=True, link='logit')


test.loc[10, 'phos_Min'] = np.NAN
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X=test)
pat = test.iloc[10]
shap.plots.force(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[10], pat, show=True, link='logit')
```

Attached below are the before and after SHAP force plots.
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHI7h.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r46ld.png)

If you see the above 2 images, the first image has many features in the high impact feature section (red), but in the second image, since I made phos_Min = np.NAN, all the features near that are missing.

Am I doing anything wrong or is that how it is?